# C Shared Object, With C++ Archive, Static Ctors/Dtors, and dlopen

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, dlopen

I have a C shared object I'm loading with `dlopen`. The C shared object includes another library as a static archive (fully specified path `/usr/local/.../libsomelib.a`). `libsomelib.a` is a C++ library and it has global and static locals.

On Ubuntu, the static initializers do not appear to run when opening the shared library with `RTLD_GLOBAL` and `RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_LAZY`. The symptom I am seeing is a program crash.

The behavior I am seeing seems similar to linking with `-nostartfiles` or `-nostdlib` (but I'm not using them). I found a similar thread at *[C++ Static Constructors and dlopen'd Shared Libraries](http://mail-index.netbsd.org/tech-toolchain/2000/03/07/0001.html)*, but its for a NetBSD system.

If the EXE explicitly includes `libsomelib.a` and calls a function from it, the C++ library will initialize and the program no longer crashes when calling through the function pointer.

EDIT: here's how the shared object is being built (its the simplest case that I've experienced, without mixing/matching C and C++). `cryptopp-so-test.exe` calls `dlopen`:

```
CXXFLAGS = -g -ggdb -fPIC -DDEBUG -O1 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused -DUSE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=1 -I. -I/usr/local/include/cryptopp
...
precompile:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) pch.h -o pch.h.gch

cryptopp-so-test.exe: precompile $(EXEOBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $(EXESOURCES) -ldl -lpthread

dsotest: precompile $(DLLOBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(DLLSOURCES) -o dsotest-1.so -shared /usr/local/lib/libcryptopp.a
```

While the code above build one EXE (cryptopp-so-test.exe) and one SO (dsotest-1.so), I actually build and load 4 shared objects (they are built identically).

What flags (or other methods) should I use to ensure the static initializers are run when a C shared object with C++ components is `dlopen`'d?

Comment: This is supposed to work without your doing anything special at `dlopen` time, so there is no special thing you can do then.   Please show how you are *creating* the shared object (the complete, unedited link command line).  If this is fixable at all, it is fixable there.

Comment: Thanks Zack. "This is supposed to work without your doing anything special..." That's what I thought. For the record, I have experienced this problem for years, but I've got to solve it now.

Comment: Q: Can you boil this down to a short, self-contained example?

Answer (score 1):

> On Ubuntu, the static initializers do not appear to run when opening the shared library with RTLD_GLOBAL and RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_LAZY.

When you `dlopen` a shared library, the global constructors *are* called. You are likely jumping to the wrong conclusions.

> The symptom I am seeing is a program crash.

That symptom could be caused by *anything*. You need to look at the crash in the debugger, and understand what is causing it, rather than blindly guess "static initializers".

One difference between linking `libsomelib.a` into the main executable and linking it into a shared library is that depending on which code calls which functions, you may end up with wildly different parts of `libsomelib.a` included into each (the linker will only pull in the parts of `libsomelib.a` that it can see are necessary).

You could try linking the *entire* `libsomelib.a` into the shared library as follows:

```
g++ $(OBJS) -o dsotest-1.so -shared \
  -Wl,--whole-archive -lsomelib -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```